# Appcelerator-Titanium - Not receiving fcm data push messages when app is in the background / closed

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, titanium

I am migrating existing GCM functionality to FCM in Appcelerator-Titanium app which is using alloy framework. 
I am using following 3rd party module for the FCM -

https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-firebase-cloud-messaging/

App was previously using following module for the GCM -

https://github.com/saurabh-vijay004/gcm.js-master

App is not receiving push data messages when in the background / closed, but working fine in foreground.

Following is sample code in my index.js -

```
var core = require('firebase.core');
    core.configure({
        file : "google-services.json"
    });
    var fcm = require('firebase.cloudmessaging');
    var androidNotification = require('/androidNotification');

    registerAndroid();
    function registerAndroid() {
        // Called when the Firebase token is registered or refreshed.
        fcm.addEventListener('didRefreshRegistrationToken', function(e) {
            Ti.API.info('Token', e.fcmToken);
            Ti.App.Properties.setString('push_token', e.fcmToken);
        });
        // Called when direct messages arrive. Note that these are different from push notifications.
        fcm.addEventListener('didReceiveMessage', function(e) {
            Ti.API.info('Message', JSON.stringify(e.message.data.message));
            androidNotification.sendNotification(e.message.data.message);
        });

        if (OS_ANDROID) {

            var channel = Ti.Android.NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel({
                id : 'nube_channel',
                name : 'NUBE CHANNEL',
                importance : Ti.Android.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT,
                enableLights : true,
                enableVibration : true,
                showBadge : true
            });
            fcm.notificationChannel = channel;
        }

        // Register the device with the FCM service.
        fcm.registerForPushNotifications();
        // Check if token is already available.
        if (fcm.fcmToken) {
            Ti.API.info('FCM-Token', fcm.fcmToken);
            Ti.App.Properties.setString('push_token', fcm.fcmToken);
        } else {
            Ti.API.info('Token is empty. Waiting for the token callback ...');
        }
    }
```

androidNotification.js file has code to show push notifications in a notification tray.

Comment: I am using FCM and I get the notification in the tray when the app is in the background or killed.

Do you mean notification does show on the tray but you are not getting the extra payload that you send from the server?
OR the notification doesn't show at all?